# VBA Macro workbook.open or workbook.activate through variable reference

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How do I reference my primary workbook and the second workbook I open through this sub procedure? I attempt to do `workbooks.("client_path").activate` as my goal with this macro is to open a separate workbook, which is assigned to variable `client_path` and reconcile every (1 to 200) values in column A:A with all the values of column K:K of my primary workbook. If a value is found on the `client_path` workbook (again column A:A), but not on my primary workbook (again column K:K) - I would like to add the unique value to column M:M of my primary workbook. Opposite logic, I would like any value found on my primary workbook but not found on my `client_path` workbook to appear in column N:N of my primary workbook.

The name of my the primary workbook which I am developing this code is title "Client DIRTY watchlist" The contents of workbook `client_path` update daily and are useless as time passes.

Do I need to create a function to accomplish this variable workbook reference?

```
Sub Client_Dirty_Recon()

Dim Client_path As String
Dim Client_watchlist As Workbook
Dim Client_client_email As Workbook
Set Client_watchlist = ActiveWorkbook
Dim email_range As Range
Dim watchlist_range As Range

Application.ScreenUpdatClient = False  
Client_path = Range("Path")
Workbooks.Open Client_path
Dim recon_list As Range

'For Each n In recon_list:
Dim i As Variant
    For i = 1 To 200

        Set email_range = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)
        Dim b As Variant

            For Each b In email_range

                Set watchlist_range = Sheets("Client DIRTY watchlist").Range("B:B")


                'if b
            Next b

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you just make references to your workbook earlier?

```
Dim wb as workbook
Dim wbDirty as workbook

set wb = thisWorkbook
set wbDirty = workbooks.open Client_Path
```

Then when you define the ranges, Excel knows which workbook they belong to.

```
Dim rngReconcile as range
Dim rngWatch as range

set rngReconcile = wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:K")
set rngWatch = wbDirty.Sheets("Client DIRTY watchlist").Range("B:B")
```

Then continue on with your looping code

Answer (score 2):

```
dim Wb as workbook

set wb= Workbooks.Open (Client_path).activate
```

this opens, and activates it all in one line, an sets a variable for later use (wb).

note that refering later to wb will NOT open it again, and NOT activate it again, its just reference to the wb ! (unless you tell him to)