# VBA - copy different template sheets from a workbook, into multiple sheets of another workbook based on criteria on a summary excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty new to VBA (3 days of exp), I have had a look through several forums but I can't find the solution.

I have 2 workbooks. The "master" workbook has a summary sheet with column A - List of names hyperlinked to a blank sheet each in the same workbook, the tabs are labelled the same as the name in the column. Column B has 1 or a combination of colour - there is 5 options (red, blue, green, blue & red, or red & green). 
 I have a separate template workbook that has 5 template sheets each one corresponding to the colour: labelled red, blue, green, blue & red, or red & green.

I want a macro that will go through column B of my "master" workbook, and depending on the colour, copy the corresponding template from the template workbook and then go back to the master workbook click through the link in the adjacent column A, which will take it through to an empty sheet and paste the template. This should repeat to go through the entire column.

For example :

1. Recognises that Cell B2 in "master" workbook has the colour red.
2. Opens the template workbook,
3. go to the sheet labelled red
4. copy entire sheet
5. Go back to "master" workbook
6. click on the hyperlinked name in the cell (A2) next to B2
7. This will take you to a blank sheet
8. Paste the template
9. Go back to "Master" workbook and repeat for the rest of the column
10. If its red again, then do the same, if a different colour like blue, then copy paste the blue template sheet.

I have tried to write a code myself from what was available in other forums, but it only copy pastes onto the first 2 sheets of the "Master" workbook out of 10 sheets that requires the red template. I have only written it for 1 colour criteria so far since no point in adding multiple criteria if 1 isn't working:

```
Sub Summary()    
Dim rng As Range    
Dim i As Long    
Set rng = Range("B:B")   
For Each cell In rng       
If cell.Value <> "Red" Then cell.Offset(0, -1).select 
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "T:\Contracts\Colour Templates.xlsx"


Sheets("Red Template").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Master.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(“A1”).select

ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: To get useful answers here, try actually doing the code and posting a specific problem. Nobody is going to write that entire code for you. You can get answers for how to do each of those individual steps on here or numerous other places!

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks for the productive comment, Unfortunately explanation to each step doesn't exist, hence the post. For the steps where there is answers for, there is no explanation on how to link them and when I try linking them together it doesn't work. so the code I ended up with (using my 3 days of coding experience) just opens the template workbook and pastes over the summary sheet of the "master" workbook. I'm pretty sure the code I have will be heavily changed or even disregarded entirely, so didn't see the point in posting it, but as per your request I will edit the original post for you.

Comment: Copying worksheets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692274/excel-vba-copy-sheet-and-get-resulting-sheet-object Opening workbooks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415179/vba-macro-workbook-open-or-workbook-activate-through-variable-reference There are answers out there... I've posted a bare-bones  code to help you learn some of the key functions you will need though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here's some code to get you started. I based the names on the code you gave, which is why it was helpful. I've commented this a lot to try and aid your learning, there are only actually about a dozen lines of code!

Note: this code will likely not work "as is". Try and adapt it, look at the Object Browser (press `F2` in VBA editor) and documentation (add "MSDN" to Google searches) to help you.

```
Sub Summary()

    ' Using the with statement means any code phrase started with "." assumes the With bit first
    ' So ActiveSheet.Range("...") can now become .Range("...")

    Dim MasterBook As Workbook
    Set MasterBook = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim HyperlinkedBook As Workbook

    With MasterBook

        ' Limit the range to column 2 (or "B") in UsedRange
        ' Looping over the entire column will be crazy long!

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(2))

    End With

    ' Open the template book
    Dim TemplateBook As Workbook
    Set TemplateBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="T:\Contracts\Colour Templates.xlsx")

    ' Dim your loop variable
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng

        ' Comparing values works here, but if "Red" might just be a
        ' part of the string, then you may want to look into InStr
        If cell.Value = "Red" Then
            ' Try to avoid using Select
            'cell.Offset(0, -1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

            ' You are better off not using hyperlinks if it is an Excel Document. Instead
            ' if the cell contains the file path, use

            Set HyperlinkedBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=cell.Offset(0, -1).Value)

            ' If this is on a network drive, you may have to check if another user has it open.
            ' This would cause it to be ReadOnly, checked using If myWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then ...

            ' Copy entire sheet
            TemplateBook.Sheets("Red Template").Copy after:=HyperlinkedBook.Sheets(HyperlinkedBook.Sheets.Count)

            ' Instead of copying whole sheet, copy UsedRange into blank sheet (copy sheet is better but here for learning)
            ' HyperlinkedBook.Sheets.Add after:=HyperlinkedBook.Sheets.Count
            ' TemplateBook.sheets("Red Template").usedrange.copy destination:=masterbook.sheets("PasteIntoThisSheetName").Range("A1")

        ElseIf cell.Value = "Blue" Then

            ' <similar stuff here>

        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Use the Macro Recorder to help you learn how to do simple tasks:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html

Try to then edit the code, and avoid using `Select`:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, This should be more than enough to finish the code. The reason why I had hyperlinks in the summary sheet is because I have a list of about 40-50 names, and once the templates are added to each respective sheet, it will be a pain scrolling through the sheets to find the relevant sheet whenever dealing with that particular individual. So is it ok to leave the hyperlinks in but use     Set HyperlinkedBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=cell.Offset(0, -1).Value).

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick under the voting arrows. Thanks.

Comment: Also regarding the red being part of the string. When I have blue & red together for example, then I have a separate template for that, and so don't want the red only template or blue only template to be pasted in (which is what happened to me). so would the "InStr" be the thing to look in to sort that out?  And finally the template doc is in a network drive, but the template is not going to get modified in any way, just copied from, so that should be possible even if it is in a read only state no? or is it different when using macros.

Comment: If you have separate templates then it is just a different string you are matching against, like "Red & Blue" then `=` should be right. Look up `InStr` in the documentation to suit your needs. Yes to copy sheets, ReadOnly is fine. You could do `set wbook = Workbooks.Open(filename:="filename", ReadOnly:=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get the code to work for the past week with no luck. I tried various modifications, which ends up giving different error codes. The first Error I was getting was with `Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(2))`   “Object doesn’t support this property or method”
So then I changed this to just going through the entire column just to see if it would work.
`Set rng = Range("B:B")`. 
When I do that then it reads through and I get an error for `Set HyperlinkedBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=cell.Offset(0, -1).Value)`  with the error code: run time error 1004 Sorry we couldn’t find 24 James.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?”
I believe that this line of the code is assuming that the hyperlink should open a different workbook with that name, however this is not the case. The hyperlink on the summary sheet links through to other sheets on the same master workbook, only the templates are on a separate book. 
So to overcome this I tried changing this line as well and ended up with the code below, which manages to open the template workbook, and copy just the tab name onto the first sheet and then gives an error for the following line `TemplateBook.Sheets("Red").Copy ActiveSheet.Paste`, saying “subscript out of range”

```
Sub Summary()

    Dim MasterBook As Workbook
    Set MasterBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With MasterBook

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range("B:B")

    End With
    Dim TemplateBook As Workbook
    Set TemplateBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\Example template.xlsx")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "Red" Then
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
            TemplateBook.Sheets("Red").Copy ActiveSheet.paste
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Blue" Then
cell.Offset(0, -1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
            TemplateBook.Sheets("Blue").Copy ActiveSheet.paste
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

I tried several more variations but I just can’t get it to copy the correct template, switch back to the master workbook, follow through the link on the summary sheet to the correct sheet (within the same master workbook), and paste the template.