# Excel Workbook won't open until VBA code has finished running

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:** Workbook won't open until the code has finished running.

**Details:** I have a loop that required the user to have another  file open, in order for the code to continue. This file has to be downloaded from the internet and opened. If the file isn't open a msgbox appears asking the user to open the file. Even though I download the file and open it, it wont open until all of the other code has been executed.

**My Thoughts:** Maybe there is something like a "Refresh", that updates the current state. I should probably add something to the existing code below that refreshes the excel workbooks and sees if something else has happened.

**Code below:** (The code is fine and works for what I need, the problem is that the workbook won't open until all the other code is complete):

```
Private Function WorkbookActive() As Boolean

' Loop until the correct workbook is open
Do Until WorkbookActive = True
    On Error Resume Next
    If Workbooks("Rapport.csv") Is Nothing Then
        If MsgBox("[Rapport.csv] - Workbook is currently not open." & vbNewLine & "Please download and open [Rapports.csv] and press OK", vbOKCancel, "Workbook not open") = vbCancel Then Exit Do
        WorkbookActive = False
    ElseIf Not Workbooks("Rapport.csv") Is Nothing Then
        WorkbookActive = True
    End If
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: FWIK, VBA use single thread, which your loop will block other action (include open workbook from Excel).  To do what you want, you may need to change your approach, ask user for the location of _Rapport.csv_, then open it in your code, and continue your program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that I have tried many approaches to this. The main problem is that when the code is running I can't open any other file.

Comment: Have you try to open file in your code? FYR: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26417509/1050927

Comment: That doesn't work either. I've tried using excel to download and open the file, but it still won't open until all of the code is complete.

Comment: can you show the code you open the _csv_? Inside the loop or outside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to make your loop "indirect", using `Application.Ontime`. Rewrite you loop this way:

```
Sub IndirectLoop()
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks("Rapport.csv").Activate
    If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub ' Done!
    If MsgBox("[Rapport.csv] - Workbook is currently not open." & vbNewLine & _
      "Please download and open [Rapports.csv] and press OK", _ 
      vbOKCancel, "Workbook not open") = vbCancel Then _
           Exit Sub ' loop cancelled by user

    ' Pause VBA and reschedule the routine for 3 seconds later
    ' Control passes here from VBA to excel to open the file by the user'
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3), "IndirectLoop"
End Sub
```

The idea is, instead of looping within your VBA routine (which keeps Excel blocked), *reschedule* the routine using `Application.Ontime`. This technique will pass the control from VBA to Excel for some moment (say 3 seconds in the code above), permitting it to do some activity, that is open the file you're waiting for.