# Office365 Excel - How to close window if Workbook.close doesn't work?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I somehow have this bug where another application has created an Excel workbook and this workbook is not closable from Excel. The application which created the workbook was a SAP custom application. We don't have access to this app but we do have access to VBA. The crazy thing is the vba:

```
myWorkbook.close
```

Does not close the workbook and instead reports `Application Defined or Object Defined error.`

In previous versions of Excel calling `myWorkbook.close` would cause VBA to crash but leave Excel unaffected, so I already know something is amiss, but not sure what... Anyway here are some things I tried to work around the issue:

- `On Error Resume Next` - just skips closing.
- Closing the SAP App which created the Excel window/workbook.
- Send keys Alt+F4 - doesn't seem to register the sent keys
- `Application.DisplayAlerts = false`
- `Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = false`
- `Application.EnableEvents = false`
- `CloseWindow(stdAcc.FromExcel().hwnd)` call `CloseWindow` Win32 API function
- Use `stdAcc.FromExcel().SendMessage(...)` to send various messages to the application window including `WM_CLOSE`, `WM_QUIT`, `WM_DESTROY`, ... These raised another error message `Cannot quit Microsoft Excel.`
- Use [`stdAcc`](https://github.com/sancarn/VBA-STD-Library/blob/master/src/WIP/stdAcc.cls) to click on the red cross - didn't seem possible as apparrently the red cross is virtual and does not implement IAccessible interface...
- User manually clicks on red cross. This works, but it's sad that we cannot automate this...

**Edit:**

After hunting through ABAP code for a few hours I finally came across how to reproduce the issue. Run the following powershell code:

```
$co = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Sheet"
$co.parent.visible = $True
```

This will add a sheet object to the current active Excel instance. Now you can try to close the workbook as above, and all options will fail. The question is, is there a way around it?

Comment: `Workbook.Close` closes a workbook. `Application.Quit` closes the host, so.. have you tried `myWorkbook.Application.Quit`?

Comment: "In previous versions of Excel calling myWorkbook.close would cause VBA to crash" ...I'd look into fixing that, this is not normal.

Comment: We need to know how your myWorkbook was created, so we can know what your problem is.

Comment: @Dy.Lee I wish i knew! I will try to decipher how on earth the SAP app is creating the workbook... I did try to recreate it with powershell but whatever I tried created a workbook with entirely seperate behaviour...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Only problem is closing the application will close all the workbooks, not just the workbook we want to close, meaning we'd have to recover all open workbooks which although isn't impossible, is difficult... But you're right I should see what that does.

Comment: @Dy.Lee See the updated post! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing because another application has 'control' of the workbook. You'll need to grab that workbook first with the vba automation server, then close it.

Assuming you're using vba in excel, then you'll need to look for the workbook that the custom SAP app has opened. If you know it's name it'll be easier! I'm assuming it's called "book1"

```
   Dim xlApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
      Set xlApp = GetObject("Book1").Application
      xlApp.Workbooks("Book1").Close (False) 'false, assuming you don't want to save it
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll give it a try. Even trying `getObject(...).close` might work... Will check! Te only concern I have is that i can see the workbook with the existing application? The workbook is called `Worksheet in RIIFLO20 (1)`

Comment: `GetObject("Worksheet in RIIFLO20").name` throws the error Automation Error - Invalid syntax. Bear in mind also the workbook has no FullName. `wb.FullName` returns `Worksheet in RIIFLO20` again. I.E. `Path` is blank/empty.

Comment: You need to assign the application object to an object, before you start doing anything with it. `Set xlApp = GetObject("Book1").Application` then `xlApp.Workbooks("Book1").Close`

Comment: no matter how I do it, I get the same `Automation Error Invalid Syntax` error. Including using xlApp var.

Comment: how are you launching the vba code? From Excel? Which line is causing the error? You say the worksheet is called `Worksheet in RIIFLO20 (1)` but you didn't have the parenthesis and number in your getObject call.

Comment: Wait....what? looking through your older comments, you're saying that `wb.FullName` returns something for the SAP workbook? In this case the automation server does have access to the object - so my answer is not the solution. You might have to post more code or examples to solve this one.

Comment: Indeed, wb.FullName returns `Worksheet in RIIFLO20 (1)`. See the updated main post. I show how SAP is creating the workbook :) (The unconventional way of creating a worksheet).

Answer (score -1):

Had this same issue, the export spreadsheets from SAP were left open after I updated to Office 365, turns out the issue is that the sheets **weren't actually open** when you tried to close them.

Solution:
I had to stop my macro to give time to excel to open this sheets using  `Application.Ontime`, followed  the instructions here:

[Excel Workbook won't open until VBA code has finished running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199508/excel-workbook-wont-open-until-vba-code-has-finished-running/42201724#42201724?newreg=4ebbe66f145849e5bea29ac49f39b39f)

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the question. This question is about inability to close instantiated `Excel.Sheet` objects. Not an inability to open them.